# Spring Bean is still null after being initialized in the configuration class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

This is my bean definition in the configuration class.

```
@Bean(name = "applicationPropertiesDataService")
public com.ing.app.data.ApplicationPropertiesDataService 
applicationPropertiesDataService() {
    return new com.ing.app.data.ApplicationPropertiesDataService();
}
```

This is my bean definition of the class where I am using the above bean.

```
@Bean(name = "appRestTemplate")
public AppRestTemplate appRestTemplate() {
    return new AppRestTemplate();
}
```

This is the AppRestTemplate class. I am getting the autowired "applicationPropertiesDataService" bean as null even though the bean is instantiated before the AppRestTemplate bean(I checked it by placing a debug point in the configuration class)

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.ing.app.data.ApplicationPropertiesDataService;
import com.ing.app.interceptor.LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor;

public class AppRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {

@Autowired
private ApplicationPropertiesDataService applicationPropertiesDataService;

public AppRestTemplate() {

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
    BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory =
        new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    this.setRequestFactory(bufferingClientHttpRequestFactory);

    if (isLoggingEnabled()) {

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add(new LoggingClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
        this.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    }
}
}

private boolean isLoggingEnabled() {
    boolean isLoggingEnabled = false;
    Optional<ApplicationProperties> applicationProperties = applicationPropertiesDataService.findByCategoryAndName(
        Constant.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_CATEGORY_AUDIT_LOGGING, Constant.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_AUDIT_LOGGING);

    if (applicationProperties.isPresent()) {
        isLoggingEnabled = Constant.CONSTANT_Y.equalsIgnoreCase(applicationProperties.get().getValue());
    }
    return isLoggingEnabled;
}
```

I am unable to figure out, why is the autowired **applicationPropertiesDataService** bean null. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show you error logs. Also show the class definition for ApplicationPropertiesDataService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manually call `new AppRestTemplate();`, that bypasses CDI(Context and Dependency Injection). To get Autowired, Spring must create the bean, not you.

There are many solutions. You can do this:

```
@Bean(name = "appRestTemplate")
public AppRestTemplate appRestTemplate(ApplicationPropertiesDataService applicationPropertiesDataService) {
    return new AppRestTemplate(applicationPropertiesDataService);
}
```

and

```
public class AppRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {

    private final ApplicationPropertiesDataService applicationPropertiesDataService;

    @Autowired
    public AppRestTemplate(ApplicationPropertiesDataService applicationPropertiesDataService) {
        this.applicationPropertiesDataService = applicationPropertiesDataService;
    }
}
```